# NGINX: Allow 403 custom error page

Tags: nginx

I have a question about custom error pages, especially the 403 one.

I have this configuration for my vhost :

```
server {
...
error_page 403 /403.html
...
location / {
    ...
    allow xx.xx.xx.xx;
    deny all;
    }
location /403.html {
    root /var/www/html/error_pages;
    allow all;
    }
}
```

The file 403.html itself is well served. But the page calls some css and images in /var/www/html/error_pages/css/file.css and /var/www/html/error_pages/img/file.png

And since I have a whitelist on "location /" all files called by 403.html get a 403 error while I put "allow all;" for "location /403.html".

What am i doing wrong?

(nginx 1.16, debian 8)

Comment: Personally I would make the error page standalone and put the styling inline.

Comment: What is the URI for `file.css` and `file.png`?

Comment: In the HTML file it is like so : href="css/file.css" and <img src="img/file.png">

Web browser call them as servername.tld/css/file.css and servername.tld/img/file.png